# Update Google Sheets data when Query changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1axRSNaAKDbA2J8mkFyp5gVIV4KTtGCQNb0wndEFqm3I/edit) with two sheets, one that holds the backend data and one that is user-facing.

Here’s Sheet1, which is hidden from normal users and has all its data entered manually:

[image: Sheet1]

Then Sheet2 auto populates from Sheet1 using a query, and asks the user for some input on each entry:

[image: Sheet2]

The problem is when data is added/removed/moved in Sheet1, the order of the query changes but the user-entered data doesn’t move accordingly. Is there a way to get the data entered in Sheet2 to update with the query from Sheet1 so they stay matched?

Comment: I'm unable to access the sample sheet. Could you share it once more? Also, let me make sure I understand what you need. Do you want the information under `Property` to be removed when the row in `Sheet1` is removed? For example: When the row with `One` and `A` is removed in `Sheet1` affecting the query on `Sheet2` the `4` under `Property` should be removed too, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link. That’s right, and if a row is added in between One and Two it should move the 6 under Property down a row. Or if One and Three are switched then the 4 and 6 should switch.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is there a way? Yes. Is it easy? Not really, it is work. If you at least have  some understanding of script and have started somewhere, people might be willing to help. Otherwise, I wouldn't count on it. Still, you might get lucky.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.